# Google Dataflow shows AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Read'

Tags: python, tensorflow, apache-beam

I am using google cloud to do a testing,  I follow the guide to run test against BigQuery . https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-cloud-dataflow-for-batch-predictions-with-tensorflow

when I run the script:

```
python prediction/run.py \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--project $PROJECT \
--staging_location $BUCKET/staging \
--temp_location $BUCKET/temp \
--job_name $PROJECT-prediction-bq \
--setup_file prediction/setup.py \
--model $BUCKET/model \
--source bq \
--input $PROJECT:mnist.images \
--output $PROJECT:mnist.predict
```

It shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prediction/run.py", line 23, in <module>
    predict.run()
  File "/home/ahuoo_com/dataflow-prediction-example/prediction/modules/predict.py", line 98, in run
    images = p | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(known_args.input))
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Read'**
```

It looks like the apache_beam package doesn't contains the attribute 'Read'. I think the example google provided in github may be wrong.  You can take a look  at the code at line 98.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-prediction-example/blob/master/prediction/modules/predict.py

Is there anyone using this guide to do a test?

Comment: Well the `apache_beam` is getting imported, see [line 21](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-prediction-example/blob/46dba7abf3da856388b3d08e4ffd46ca56d67b1d/prediction/modules/predict.py#L21).

Make sure the module is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there's a small mistake in the code. In line `98` where it says:

```
images = p | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(known_args.input))
```

It should be:

```
images = p | 'ReadFromBQ' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(known_args.input))
```

Also, at line `100` where it says:

```
predictions | 'WriteToBQ' >> beam.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(...))
```

it should also be like:

```
predictions | 'WriteToBQ' >> beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(...))
```

The PCollection Reading/ Writing resources comes from the `io` module and not `apache_beam` itself.